# NFC listener trigger based on tag

Tags: android, triggers, listener, nfc

I am doing a research on NFC and its use, I've started with a simple proof of concept by creating an NFC application for Android. When tag is scanned, it sends REST request with tag's ID to see whether it is registered with the service, and if is, content is downloaded and played on the phone.

The problem is tags' ID are sequential, the requirement is to have some unique random information stored to avoid possible complications and security issues. The question is, what should the data be? Is there some standard on the subject?

The idea is to store `x,y` where `x` is trigger identifier and `y` is a random unique number. Would this work? Can custom activity be started based on `x` value?

Any help and references are appreciated. There will be cake.

Comment: Yeah well there *better* be cake.

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do. Are you trying to use a phone's NFC tag ID to be a unique value as a key for a content subscription? I don't think that's going to work for you by itself. Or will the NFC tags be in locations that the user will visit in order to get content? And you want to restrict the content only to people who are actually where the tag is?

Comment: @Dave NFC tags will be in different locations. What I'm trying to understand is how to programme them in order for application to recognize them. For example, tags with ID/NDEF `MyApp.123`, `MyApp.456` are recognized by the application based on `MyApp`, everything else is handled by default handler. What I'm trying to figure out is whether this approach is possible at all, and if not, is there some other way. @Daniel There will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to check out this page, which describes the latest dispatch process for a newly-detected tag: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html. It now makes a difference if your tag-detecting app is expected to be running at the time the tag is scanned. If it's in the foreground, you can be sure that your activity is going to get first crack at a scanned tag, whatever tag is detected. If your app is not already running but is installed on the device, then the intent filter(s) in your AndroidManifest.xml will dictate whether or not your app has a chance at being notified of the detected tag. Previously, all tag data was put into the extras of the intent that was sent out. But in 2.3.3, if there is a URI in the tag's first NDEF record, and the tag is URI or SmartPoster, that URI gets put into the intent's data field, which will be used when matching against intent filters. If the tag is a MIME_TYPE tag, the mime type is put into the intent's type field. Therefore, if you use a custom URI or custom MIME type that your app is looking for, you should always get notified of your tags (unless another app is in the foreground and has requested all tags).

Comment: Send me your address please :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a plugin I developed for NFC (phonegap) and I simply use:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/pg" />
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I used the FakeTagsActivity to load NDEF message into NFCAdapter. I am passing the URI/text message through an intent. But unable to launch the TagViewer activity with following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="mimeType/pg" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>     
</intent-filter>
```